# Symfony 2 - Generating a Bundle (Windows)

Tags: php, symfony, cmd

I am new to Symfony. I am running Windows and am using xammp to learn Symfony 2. How would I run the following command? I seem to be getting an error and not sure how to run commands like these successfully. I appreciate any suggestions. Must I use CMD to create a bundle for Symfony2? Is there an easier way to generate a bundle?

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml
```

Comment: `I seem to be getting an error`. You are either getting an error or not. If you are what is it?

Comment: Also, what happens if you type `php app/console` into the CLI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: and the answer to my second comment?

Comment: Getting the following error: `Could not open the input file app/console `

Comment: are you in the root of your app?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Symfony, can you please elaborate? what is the root of my app? the Symfony root directory? is it `Symfony/web/`?

Comment: no one level up from there

Comment: Got it, now I'm getting a long list of information such as options, commands, etc, when I run `app/console`.

Comment: ok `php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle` should work for you now

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm up and running right now! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CLI tools is the easiest way to generate a bundle and many other things in symfony2.

Make sure you are in the root of your app to use the `php app/console` utility. If you 'dir', then you should see something like:-

```
28/09/2013  18:13    <DIR>          .
28/09/2013  18:13    <DIR>          ..
25/03/2013  12:50    <DIR>          app
01/03/2013  23:40             1,790 composer.json
09/03/2013  20:28            39,452 composer.lock
24/07/2013  12:41    <DIR>          data
01/03/2013  23:40             1,084 LICENSE
01/03/2013  23:40             6,202 README.md
01/03/2013  23:40    <DIR>          src
01/03/2013  23:40             8,393 UPGRADE.md
02/03/2013  13:29    <DIR>          vendor
07/04/2013  17:12    <DIR>          web
```